# Can't change h2 color in CSS

Tags: css, weebly

Trying to change h2 color from 3f3e3c to FF1494 in CSS, but the change doesn't seem to be taking effect when I publish it.

```
h2 {
  font-size: 36px ;
  padding: .5em 0 .2em 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #FF1494;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks

Also tried clearing the cache, no luck. Note - I'm customizing a theme in Weebly. Is there something else I should look for that might be preventing my change?

Comment: Does the weebly code use a class name? If so, thats what you need to target in your CSS

Comment: You are showing us the crayons but not the picture you are trying to color so anything we say, without the HTML or a link, is just a wild guess.

Comment: Let's see, you looked at this in style inspector, right? And you found...what??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've already changed the color on another `h2`, use `!important` after the color, it might help.

```
h2 {
  font-size: 36px ;
  padding: .5em 0 .2em 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #FF1494 !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add a } at the end of the h2 . (or if it's just a typo on SO, try clearing your browser's cache)

```
h2 {
    font-size: 36px ;
    padding: .5em 0 .2em 0;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #FF1494;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
} <- add this
```